# Webpack load legacy code

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I'm a Webpack beginner who is trying to refactor an old JavaScript/jQuery application by decomposing it in several ES6 module usign Webpack and Babel.

So far i've managed to refactor the core components of the application, but now i'm stucked with a module that requires jQuery (v2.2) and another library ( [`BIMsurfer @V1`](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMsurfer/tree/V1)) available on the global scope.

The problem is that the BIMsurfer library isn't designed as a module and uses Grunt to produce a minified file.

I've seen that i could use the `webpack.ProvidePlugin` but i'm getting this error:

`TypeError: $.extend is not a function [bimsurfer.js:14]`

I've created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GiacomoManzoli/WebpackTest)  with the minimal code to reproduce the error.

My goal is to produce a single bundle with my JavaScript library that can be re-used in several application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded your repo and did some test. The webpack config is fine. But there are other problems you need to fix.

1. the src/libs/jquery.js file is empty.
2. in the src/libs/bimsurfer/bimsurfer.js file, at line 15015 and 22438, the declaration of WebGLDebugUtils and SceneJS_PubSubProxy are missing the `var` keyword.

once you fix these two problem, you should be able to see a clean console in chrome devtool.

Comment: Thank you! the `jquery` was a mistake of the example... i've also fixed the other one and now it works. But there is something else that bugs me: the BIMsurfer file is the same one that it's used in the legacy version of the application and, in that application, works fine without adding the missing `var`. Why? It's something specific to the Webpack bundle or there is an error on the original repo?

Comment: if you check the output bundle file, you will find that webpack add `use strict;` to all modules by default.  ![screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1198651/39671327-88cac93c-5148-11e8-888b-5926dc0bcc19.png). That's why you got an error.For more detail, check [MDN: Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and [here](http://qnimate.com/javascript-strict-mode-in-nutshell/#Use_of_undeclared_variable)